# Masking data in the existing table

Tags: sql, data-masking, sql-masking

I am looking to mask the data(Columns) in the existing table without creating a new table and sensitive data(Columns) like Name, Mailid, phone number etc...

Can someone help me with the query.

Lets think we have a table(Empsal) with columns
name
mobile no
ID
salary
department

Now I want to mask the complete data in the columns mobileno,Name,ID

Can someone help me with the SQL query without creating a new data this table already exists in the database and need to do masking for the existing table.

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. Also, please update your question with more information on how you want to mask the data (with examples) and whether it should be masked for everyone or should some people be able to see the unmasked data?

Comment: You can: 1) Replace the data you want to hide (aka scrubbing, sanitize, masking) effectively losing it, or 2) you can create a view that masks it, while at the same time hiding the original table using permissions.

Comment: Data should be masked for everyone and I am Using IBM  DB2 Database.
And the data should be complete masked Like In Name(Column) Mahesh It should be completly masked as xxxxxx and mail Id ---xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com

Comment: OK then the options provided by @TheImpaler should cover you

Comment: @NickW But I am looking for a query how to mask

Comment: 1) Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using 2) Assuming your DBMS doesn't support its own proprietary masking functionality, are you trying to physically update the values in the columns (so that the original values no longer exist) or are you trying to create a view over the table so the original values still exist in the table but users with only access to the view will only see the masked values?

Comment: Hi @NickW,

Its like there is an existing table and I want to mask the sensitive data and export that table to other database so that the users in that database can only see the masked data